# WEIRD ISSUE! Values are returning in different code structures based on server

Tags: reactjs, server, redux, redux-form

I am using Redux Form and have run into what seems to be a really strange issue! I made an update that worked perfectly on my local branch, but when pushed up to the develop branch which gets built to a specific ip via codeship my values seem to be different. So when testing the remote development IP, I got this error

```
form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields.find in not a function
```

So instantly I thought well either form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields doesn't exist at a certain point and therefore is breaking or the structure of my value is fudged. After a few console logs I noticed that is was my second assumption.

So is where it gets weird for me, on my local branch (exact same code!) when I console log form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields I get an array of objects which is great.
[image]

But when I console the exact same value on my development server I get the same shit, but is an object instead

[image]

Maybe Im just losing my mind on a Friday, but this doesn't make sense in my eyes, the only thing I can think of is either codeship is being funky or there is some sort of issue with naming conventions between servers. Both of these ideas shouldn't be an issue as codeship has always been good to me prior to this issue, and I didnt add any new files or anything that should be messing up.

Its a little messy but this is what the section of code looks like that is performing this task (I removed the extra stuff and just left the console for example):

```
let shippingValues = {};
if (form.ProcessCheckoutForm) {
    const oldSuffix = '_shipping';
    const newSuffix = '_billing';
    Object.keys(form.ProcessCheckoutForm.values).forEach(field => {
        const prefix = field.substring(0, field.length - oldSuffix.length);
        if (form.ProcessCheckoutForm.fields) {
            console.log('registeredFields', form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so no idea why this is happening but I worked out a "fix(aka gross condition to fix any instance of this in future)". All I did was convert the object version into an array of object using the Object.values method.

So my "fix" looks a little like this:

```
let registeredFields = form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields;
if (form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields.constructor != Array) {
    registeredFields = Object.values(form.ProcessCheckoutForm.registeredFields);
}
```

gross I know, so if anyone has any suggestion please let me know